# Is it possible to remove blood in No Man's Sky?

Tags: no-mans-sky

ESRB says that "some creatures emit large splatters of green blood when shot."  Is it possible to disable this?  I prefer to have no blood in games.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It would seem that the answer is no, you cannot turn off the green blood. PVP is optional for the game, so red blood from players is avoidable, but blood from creatures is not. You could avoid this by not killing any creatures, but that may not be possible.

I tried looking for mods as well, but there are only ones that *enhance* the blood effects, nothing for removing them. Sorry!

Comment: the mods to "enhance" blood are there because blood in the game is so minimal. OP, I don't think you need to worry about it. "Biological horrors" are the only creatures that emit this blood. and combat with them is very avoidable and never required.

Comment: "Biological horrors" are the only creatures that emit this blood".  Have the devs said this, or is this just the guess of the players?  Also, if I leave their eggs alone they wont attack me and I wont have to attack them correct?

Comment: Thanks to Kaizerwolf for his research and answering my question.  I would still like to confirm that Biological horrors are the only creatures with blood, maybe I should ask another question about that.  Thanks to Rapitor, also.  =)

Comment: @Millard be aware that some in-game task require you to battle horrors and not every one may be skipable - especially if Expedition milestone are involved.

Comment: What exactly are biological horrors?  Giant insects?  Dinosaur-like?

Comment: For the record and for anyone who reads this post, from what I've seen on the internet, you can turn off the red blood, but not the green blood.